# Why setting titleView lowers header text?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to dynamically set my navigation bar's text so that the header text always fits. I'm acccomplishing that like this:

```
// Pet's Day text "Joy's Day"
if let range = currentPet.range(of: "_") {
    let petsName = currentPet[range.upperBound..<currentPet.endIndex]
    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: deviceWidth, height: 40))
    titleLabel.text = "\(petsName)'s Day"
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

However, as seen by this picture, this lowers the header text below its natural height:

[image: pic]

The navigation bar on the left is from one of my app's other views, while the one on the right is the one I'm setting.

Both of these navigation bars are navigation bars that I've dragged in and made the prompt equal to an empty string to increase their height:

[image: pic2]

[image: pic2]

Can anybody please help me implement my code above so that it doesn't drop down the header text?

**Edit: Here are screenshots from Xcode's debug hierarchy:

This is the normal navigation bar:

[image: pic4]

This is the one I'm setting:

[image: pic5]

Comment: For one thing the height of the label should be `44`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the baseline, by default is `Align Baseline`, you need to change to `Align Centers`

[image]

Code example:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Change the height of the navbar
        self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 68)
        let deviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: deviceWidth, height: 40))
        titleLabel.text = "Log Events" // Change to Joy's Day and check the result
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        titleLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignBaselines
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = titleLabel
    }

}
```

Comment: I reproduced your code here with the `.baselineAdjustment` and I got the titles aligned. I put the result in my answer. If you are using the Storyboard to set the Log Events, maybe the default baseline of the title is different from the label that you are putting programmatically. Try to set both programmatically.

Comment: Is that a normal navigation bar? Mine is one that I dragged in and set the prompt to `" "` to increase its height

Comment: This was with the Navigation Controller, I will do with the one from the builder

Comment: I edited my answer with new images. In this case I set both programmatically and I could find the result that you want.

Comment: Weird, I'm using the exact same code as you and it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152351/discussion-between-kileros-and-markscode).

Comment: I talk to you in the chat. Did you try create a new ViewController in Storyboard using my example class?